# Set condition to style expression

Tags: angularjs

I read about ngClass in angularjs docs looked at different issues, but i still dont understand how to solve my simple problem with angular...

I have a simple button in html

```
<div class="form-group">
<button ng-click="displayMessage();">Change color</button>
</div>
```

By click on this button, function displayMessage analyze input-field (i didnt show it here) and returns one message from three, it depends from condition.

```
$scope.message = firstMessage;
$scope.message = secondMessage;
$scope.message = thirdMessage;
```

This message is expression. And validates with "if" in my app.js

```
<div class="form-group message">
{{message}}
</div>
```

**And my problem** is to change style of my message depending what message now is showing.
For example if it validates with firstMessage - this message should be green.
If it secondMessage - yellow...
And so on.

As i understand i need to manipulate with ng-class, but i could imagine how it works without good example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store message and class associated with it in an object and use it in your html

```
$scope.message = {
 "message" : "firstMessage",
 "class" : "red"

}
```

in HTML

```
<div ng-class="message.class" class="form-group message">
    {{message.message}}
</div>
```

in CSS

```
.red {
  //whatever styling you want
}
```

Please have a look at  [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BEC9OoFMJP3o3dZfopvB?p=preview)